# AJAX Response Text Is Always Empty

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax

I'm using asp.net web forms and trying to call a web service method from a java script function using AJAX which returns a JSON array with a car number and a car number ID pairs
the web methods resides in the same code behind file of the java script function page
I checked the json variable more than one time using the debugger and made sure it holds a valid JSON array
however when I checked the cars object in the FillLimoCars java script function I found the response text to be an empty array
I'm not sure why this is happening I hope that anyone of you would be able to help

Java Script

```
            function testButton(carModelID) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseURL + "WebPages/NewPages/ListCarRental.aspx/FillLimoCars",
                data: "{CarModelID:'" + carModelID + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                complete: FillLimoCar
                });
        }

        function FillLimoCar(cars)
        {
            var rdd_LimoCars = $find("<%=rdd_LimoCarNumber.ClientID %>");
            var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            for(var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++)
            {
                ;
            }
        }
```

C#

```
    [WebMethod]
public static string FillLimoCars(int CarModelID)
{
    try
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<LimoFleet> limos = carsBLL.GetCarModelLimoFleet(CarModelID);
        List<object> objLimosList = new List<object>();
        foreach(var limo in limos)
        {
            var limoObj = new
            {
                CarID = limo.CarID,
                CarNumber = limo.CarNumber
            };
            objLimosList.Add(limoObj);
        }
        var json = serializer.Serialize(objLimosList);
        return json;
        //Context.Response.Write(objLimos.ToJson());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Tracer.Singleton.Log(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked your FillLimoCars function to verify it's returning a value to begin with?

Comment: @Sergio 
yes and it's returning a valid JSON array as I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You have to use success attribute. Inside success, you have to de serialize JSON object.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseURL +     "WebPages/NewPages/ListCarRental.aspx/FillLimoCars",
                data: "{CarModelID:'" + carModelID + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                "success": function (json) {
                      if (json.d != null) {
                              FillLimoCars(json.d);
                          }
                  });
```

Comment: I tried using the success attribute still got the same result, I'm not seeing why would it make a difference anyway

Comment: Try to dubug in browser. Log the ouput console.log(json.d) and see what it's returning.

Comment: already done that and it's returning an empty array "{"d":"[]"}" @Pradeep

Comment: Problem is with your server side. Please ensure the objLimosList is not empty. if it is not empty, use Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert to serialize the object. Syntax is JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objLimosList)

Comment: Just tried using the Newtonsoft serializer and got the same result, I don't think the problem is in how the object is serialized as mentioned earlier, I checked that the object is serializer just fine

Comment: Try using a non static web method. I just suspect it as other piece of code is fine.

Comment: I can't use non-static method because the web method is inside the aspx file as mentioned above

Comment: Use web service (asmx) to avoid confusion. It's just a suggestion and a best practice too.

Comment: I can't do that for other technical reasons related to the project, anyway using it inside the aspx file shouldn't be a problem